Can Parameshvara's formula be proven without trigonometry?
Parameshvara's formula connects sides of cyclic quadrilaterals with its circumradius and area.
Ptolemy's theorem can be proven by triangle similarity, as shown here. Brahmagupta's formula can also be proven without trigonometry as shown here.
Second Ptolemy's theorem about the ratio of diagonals of cyclic quadrilateral is proven as follows:

Let a cyclic quadrilateral with area $S$ have sides of lengths $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and diagonals of lengths $d_1$ and $d_2$. Let diagonal $d_1$ split this quadrilateral into two triangles with sides $a$, $b$, $d_1$, and $b$, $c$, $d_1$, and diagonal $d_2$ split this quadrilateral into two triangles with sides $b$, $c$, $d_2$ and $a$, $d$, $d_2$.
Since area of the triangle with circumradius $R$ and sides $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be expressed as $\dfrac{abc}{4R}$, we have:
$$
S_1 = \dfrac{add_2}{4R}, \ \ \ S_2 = \dfrac{bcd_2}{4R},\ \ \ \ \ S = S_1+S_2
$$
Therefore:
$$
S = \dfrac{add_2}{4R} + \dfrac{bcd_2}{4R} = \dfrac{add_2+bcd_2}{4R} = \dfrac{d_2(ad+bc)}{4R} \Rightarrow d_2 = \frac{4RS}{ad+bc}
$$
In the same way from the other pair of triangles we get:
$$
S = \dfrac{d_1(ab+cd)}{4R} \Rightarrow d_1 = \dfrac{4RS}{ab+cd}
$$
Therefore:
$$
\dfrac{d_1}{d_2} = \dfrac{4RS / (ab+cd)}{4RS / (ad+bc)} = \dfrac{ab+cd}{ad+bc}
$$

Parameshvara's formula proof of which I know is based on the second Ptolemy theorem and law of sines. Can it be derived without trigonometry?

Without a closer look, the following is closely related: https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2007volume7/FG200720.pdf
